# Get child element attribute using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html structure. I want to get all controltypeid value in a function. I just try like

```js
$('#firstDiv > a.[controltypeid]').each(function (i, val) {
  $Control = $(val);
});
```

```html
<div id="firstDiv">
  <a id="1" controltypeid="1"></a>
  <a id="2" controltypeid="2"></a>
  <a id="3" controltypeid="3"></a>
</div>
```

but I can't get the value.Can any one help. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

Done using jquery **children** selector.

Description :Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements.

Code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#firstDiv").children('a[controltypeid]').each(function(){
alert($(this).attr('controltypeid'))
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstDiv">
<a id="1" controltypeid="1"></a>
<a id="2" controltypeid="2"></a>
<a id="3" controltypeid="3"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use simply like this

```
$('#firstDiv a').each(function () {
  alert($(this).attr('controltypeid'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.[controltypeid]` is wrong and is replaced by `a[controltypeid]`

secondly, use `attr()` to get the attribute value.

```
$('#firstDiv > a[controltypeid]').each(function () {
 console.log( $( this ).attr( "controltypeid" ) );
});
```

if you just want to get all the values in a string

```
var controltypeids = [];
$('#firstDiv > a[controltypeid]').each(function () {
 controltypeids.push( $( this ).attr( "controltypeid" ) );
 console.log( $( this ).attr( "controltypeid" ) );
});
alert( controltypeids.join( "," ) );
```

Comment: @usandfriends explained in the post now

Comment: @usandfriends I still don't get it. Result could be achievable in 10 possible ways, based on what are you saying that `.map` is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need your controltypeid in a array:

```
var controltypeid = [];
$('#firstDiv > a[controltypeid]').each(function (i, v) {
 controltypeid.push($(v).attr( "controltypeid" ));
});
console.log(controltypeid);
```

Comment: i is the index of the array and v is the value at the postion i

Answer (score 0):

Did everyone forget about [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)?

Example:

```
var controlTypeIds = $('#firstDiv').children().map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('controltypeid');
}); // ['1', '2', '3']
```

Or, if you want to continue using your selector, remove the extra `.`. The `.` selector selects class, but having a attribute selector right after it `.[...]` makes no sense and is not syntactically correct.

```
var controlTypeIds = $('#firstDiv>a[controltypeid]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('controltypeid');
}); // ['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get following way using JQuery. using **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Make following changes in Jquery.

```js
$('#firstDiv > a').each(function () {
  alert($(this).attr('controltypeid'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstDiv">
  <a id="1" controltypeid="1"></a>
  <a id="2" controltypeid="2"></a>
  <a id="3" controltypeid="3"></a>
</div>
```